# Double click vs Single click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouseevent

I'm making an Inventory system in Unity. Single clicks are "picking up" the items and putting it somewhere in your inventory while double clicks should equip the item.

```
public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (this.item != null)
        {
            UICraftResult craftResult = GetComponent<UICraftResult>();
            if (eventData.clickCount == 2)
            {
                EquipItem(this.item);
            }
            else if (craftResult != null && this.item != null && selectedItem.item == null)
            {
                craftResult.PickItem();
                selectedItem.UpdateItem(this.item);
                craftResult.ClearSlots();
            }
            else if (!craftingResultSlot)
            {
                if (selectedItem.item != null)
                {
                    Item clone = new Item(selectedItem.item);
                    selectedItem.UpdateItem(this.item);
                    UpdateItem(clone);
                }
                else
                {
                    selectedItem.UpdateItem(this.item);
                    UpdateItem(null);
                }
            }
```

For some reason only triple clicks trigger the "if (eventData.clickCount == 2)" check. Also the single click will always trigger even when I double click. Can someone help? me?

Answer (score 0):

Each click is triggered individually, so your local variable `eventData` will be reset on each trigger; it is event specific.
Try creating a global variable which you can increment and then read from whenever and event is triggered.

```
public class InventoryManager : MonoBehaviour {
    int slotID = -1; //id of the previously clicked slot

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData) {
        if (this.slotID != selectedItem.id) {
            this.slotID = selectedItem.id;
            //your code for a single click
        } else {
            this.slotID = -1; //clear the slot id;
            //your code for a double click
        }
    }
}
```

Now there still remains the timing problem: This way it will always trigger the single click event and then the double click event. If you want to conditionally skip the single click event, you could make it wait for a second before triggerign the single click event. Hopefully the single click event does not much, so you can adjust the double click handler to undo what the single click handler did.
E.g. if an item was picked up and the user immediately clicks the same slot a second time, you can just place the item back in the slot and execute the event for a double click. A timer is probably optional as long as it's possible to undo the single click.

Comment: You mean with an int that I increase based on clickcount?

Comment: Exactly, you can define a variable at class-scope (assuming this class is focused on your inventory). it's probably good to store the item slot id as well, so that you will know when to reset the click counter because a different item was clicked on.

Comment: And after that make specific functions based on the new variables count?
Sorry very new to this.

Comment: No problem. The event's clickCount is probably not enough as it lacks information about what was clicked on before and it doesn't tell you how much time has passed. You should define one custom variable to determine. See my updated answer.